# How to use credentials from one auto mount in another auto mount?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab

How do I use a credentials file from one mount in a second mount so it will mount automatically on startup?

Here's my fstab.

```
1.2.3.4:/nfsroot/abc /mnt/abc nfs4 ...
//def/ghi /mnt/def/ cifs credentials=/mnt/abc/credential.txt ...
```

And the cifs mount fails on startup, presumably because the nfs mount is not ready, so no credentials available.

Manual mount works after startup.

Hardcoding username=x and password=y in the cifs mount works on startup.

Is there a delay I can set?